# Cannot modify a registered custom post type rewrite slug

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, url-rewriting, child-theme

I'm using this function in my child theme to modify the rewrite slug from custom post type that was registered on the parent theme. But it doesn't work.

```
function change_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $rewrite = $wp_post_types['holiday']->rewrite;
    $rewrite['slug'] = '%holiday_category%';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'change_rewrite_rules' );
```

Is there something wrong here?

Ps: I cannot touch the parent theme since it's a commercial one and it will get updated often.

**Update:**

I also have these functions:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);

function territorio_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%holiday_category%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

// Get post
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;

// Get taxonomy terms
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'holiday_category','orderby=term_order');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
$taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug; //build here
else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-yet';

return str_replace('%holiday_category%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you take the code from the parent theme which registers the CPT and use it in your child theme?

Comment: Because it's deeply integrated in theme framework. Plus, the company who made the theme said is no possible to have that CPT on child themes.

Comment: Link to your site please.

Comment: Sorry, it's on my local machine.

Comment: Your top most code portion isn't saving those changes to anywhere, you're just creating a new variable with data, and doing nothing with it.

Comment: So, what is the right code?